# Round 2. Extremely new to Bootstrap. Tutorial code not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I accidentally posted this unfinished earlier, so I deleted the post and remade it. This is the complete post.

Tutorial code from W3:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Fixed layout example with Twitter Bootstrap</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span4"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam cursus. Morbi ut mi. Nullam enim leo, egestas id, condimentum at, laoreet mattis, massa. Sed eleifend nonummy diam. Praesent mauris ante, elementum et, bibendum at, posuere sit amet, nibh. Duis tincidunt lectus quis dui viverra vestibulum. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui. Nulla elementum dui ut augue. Aliquam vehicula mi at mauris. Maecenas placerat, nisl at consequat rhoncus, sem nunc gravida justo, quis eleifend arcu velit quis lacus. Morbi magna magna, tincidunt a, mattis non, imperdiet vitae, tellus. Sed odio est, auctor ac, sollicitudin in, consequat vitae, orci. Fusce id felis. Vivamus sollicitudin metus eget eros.</p></div>
      <div class="span4"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam cursus. Morbi ut mi. Nullam enim leo, egestas id, condimentum at, laoreet mattis, massa. Sed eleifend nonummy diam. Praesent mauris ante, elementum et, bibendum at, posuere sit amet, nibh. Duis tincidunt lectus quis dui viverra vestibulum. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui. Nulla elementum dui ut augue. Aliquam vehicula mi at mauris. Maecenas placerat, nisl at consequat rhoncus, sem nunc gravida justo, quis eleifend arcu velit quis lacus. Morbi magna magna, tincidunt a, mattis non, imperdiet vitae, tellus. Sed odio est, auctor ac, sollicitudin in, consequat vitae, orci. Fusce id felis. Vivamus sollicitudin metus eget eros.</p></div>
      <div class="span4"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam cursus. Morbi ut mi. Nullam enim leo, egestas id, condimentum at, laoreet mattis, massa. Sed eleifend nonummy diam. Praesent mauris ante, elementum et, bibendum at, posuere sit amet, nibh. Duis tincidunt lectus quis dui viverra vestibulum. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui. Nulla elementum dui ut augue. Aliquam vehicula mi at mauris. Maecenas placerat, nisl at consequat rhoncus, sem nunc gravida justo, quis eleifend arcu velit quis lacus. Morbi magna magna, tincidunt a, mattis non, imperdiet vitae, tellus. Sed odio est, auctor ac, sollicitudin in, consequat vitae, orci. Fusce id felis. Vivamus sollicitudin metus eget eros.</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My file structure:

```
|index.html
|bootstrap
    |
    |css
        bootstrap.css
        bootstrap.min.css
    |js
        bootstrap.js
        bootstrap.min.js
```

---

The issue is that the tutorial says that the code should generate this: http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/fixed-layout-example.html

However, when I run it the text just floods the screen and is not caught in the container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not include the `<div class="container">` line from the tutorial example:

```
[...]
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
[...]
```

Comment: I added the container class, which did do something but did not end up formatting the text in the same way that the tutorial suggests.

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted from w3resource is using Bootstrap v2.3.2

In current Bootstrap v3.0.0, **span** is replaced with **col-**.

It should be -

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4"><p>...</p></div>
      <div class="col-4"><p>...</p></div>
      <div class="col-4"><p>...</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xrsMb/